# How to set the panel on the custom webpart without scrollbars

Tags: web-part

We have a panel in our custom webpart & its size is set as equal to the webparts size on the createchildcontrol method...however the panel is coming up with scrollbars..

how we can display the panel on the webpart without the scrollbars..?

Answer (score 1):

U should specify the content width and height which is inside the panel, that should not greater then the panel hight and width. Other wise it will show the scroll bar for panel.u dont have any contrain in webaprt hight and width then u can use auto , use 100% height and width to panel.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you should set height and width by zone in the web part properties in browser.